# What is the best method to bind an JS event to a link?

Tags: javascript, html, methods, hyperlink, bind

What is the best way and why?

Href?

```
<a href="javascript:helloworld()">link</a>
```

onclick?

```
<a href="#" onClick="helloworld()">link</a>
```

bind by framework (e.g. jquery)?

```
<a id="foo" href="#">link</a>
…
$('#foo').live('click',helloworld);
```

Comment: I think a relevant question is why, if you don't want the clicks to trigger a page reload like an `<a>` tag normally does, you're using an `<a>` tag at all.

Comment: The last one of course, because it separates the content from behavior.

Comment: @Pointy Because anchors are accessible via TAB, and a SPAN for instance, isn't. Buttons on the other hand, have presentational issues (they're not as easy to style with CSS).

Comment: @ŠimeVidas, add `[tabindex="0"]` and `[role="button"]` to a `<span>` and you've got yourself a button. `<a href="#">link</a>` doesn't do "nothing", it scrolls the viewport back to the top of the page. It can be useful to leave it in for Non-js users if you have a message at the top that says something like "JavaScript is required on this website, please read the instructions for enabling JavaScript." I know it's not always good to require JavaScript, but for webapps it can make sense.

Comment: @zzzzBov The `tabindex` attribute will make the SPAN element accessible via TAB, however pressing ENTER won't activate it. (Pressing ENTER while an anchor is focused, activates it.) See here: http://jsfiddle.net/NMwdj/

Comment: Cant we instrument the desired element to receive focus? `href="#"` is pure crap.

Comment: Anyway, we can style button to look like a link and it already behaves like a link.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas, that's because you need to listen for the right events. The beauty of creating a custom button is that you as the developer get to determine the default interactions. [WAI-ARIA](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/) has some suggestions for maintaining consistency for accessibility, but it's known that they may not be appropriate in all instances. A web-based video game could use the arrow keys for moving a character (think Legend of Zelda, not Counter-Strike) about on the screen, and provide a button-interface where it would be inappropriate for `ENTER` to trigger the focused element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends. Usually, you should *never* have a link that does nothing. What if your users have JavaScript disabled, or it fails to load? You *must* degrade gracefully to have an accessible website. So, for example, if you have a box that loads with Ajax, you should have it link to an alternative page, then bind the handler in unobtrusive, separate JavaScript:

```
<a class="loadPage" href="actualPage.php">Go to my page</a>
```

and in *another file*:

```
$('.loadPage').click(function(e) {
    // Load with Ajax...
    e.preventDefault(); // Stop the link from going through
});
```

If the links were generated with JavaScript, then it's okay to use `#` as an `href` most of the time. However, in that case, you should still be attaching the handlers with JavaScript as opposed to setting `onclick` in `innerHTML` (*shudder*).

So, generally: if you have an `onclick` attribute or `javascript:` link in production code, right in your HTML, you're not separating content, behaviour and presentation; you're not being accessible; and you're not being semantic. Don't do it!

Answer (score 2):

None of the above.

You should keep the JS in an external file (separation of concerns makes for more manageable and reusable code), and using a library does smooth over the differences between browsers that support standard event binding and older versions of Internet Explorer.

However, JavaScript should be [unobtrusive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript). You should not start out with a link to the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use 'javascript:myaction()' .

Always prefer the usage of a framework, as it create a real bind (meaning registering the event with the browser window). 
So the best way to go is : 
$('#foo').live('click',function(){my action.... });

it will also allow you to keep your javascript in a separate file, which is the best practices for dealing with scripts.

the second best way to go is using the onClick event.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use javaScript in HTML markup!

```
$(function() {
   var foo = $('#foo');

   if(foo[0]) {
      foo.click(function(event) {
          //..
          event.preventDefault();
      });
   }
});
```

or use `on()` since `jQuery 1.7+`

```
foo.on('click', function(event) {
   //..
   event.preventDefault();
});
```

Also don't use `live()` never (As of `jQuery 1.7`, the `.live()` method is deprecated)!